# R: weightTf and weightTfIdf yield the same frequent word list?

Tags: r, tf-idf

I recognised today, that `tf` and/or `tfidf` seems to be broken in R. See my example below. It uses the data from the manual i.e. `crude`. I would expect, that the resulting frequent term lists are not equal. But they are equal. This should never happen, right?

```
data("crude")

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTf, stopwords = FALSE))
frequentTerms1 <- data.frame(findFreqTerms(dtm)[1:1000])
#View(frequentTerms1)


dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE), stopwords = FALSE))
frequentTerms2 <- data.frame(findFreqTerms(dtm)[1:1000])
#View(frequentTerms2)

frequentTerms1 == frequentTerms2
```

Do I have any mistake in the example code? I copied it from the manual of the underlying `tm` package and added an `tf` case as well as the comparison.

Thanks for any advice.

Best regards
Thorsten

---

**Edit #1:**
Okay, thanks `lukeA` for the answer. That helps a lot. Therefore, the "right" way to get the frequent terms is:

```
data("crude")

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTf, stopwords = FALSE))
frequentTerms1 <- as.data.frame(sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing = TRUE))
#View(frequentTerms1)


dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE), stopwords = FALSE))
frequentTerms2 <- as.data.frame(sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing = TRUE))
#View(frequentTerms2)

frequentTerms1 == frequentTerms2
```

Now, both lists are differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `findFreqTerms` checks, if the row sums of the transposed document-term-matrix (= term-document-matrix) are greater or equal than 0 and smaller or equal than infinity. That's true for all terms using frequency weighting as well as tfidf weighting. Here's an example:

```
txts <- c("Hello super World", "Hello World World")
corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(txts))
tf <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp, control=list(weighting=weightTf))
tfidf <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp, control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf))

all(findFreqTerms(tf)==findFreqTerms(tfidf))
# [1] TRUE
```

Now, if you specify for example another minimum frequency:

```
findFreqTerms(tf, lowfreq = 1)
# [1] "hello" "super" "world"
findFreqTerms(tfidf, lowfreq = 0.33)
# [1] "super"
```

with

```
as.matrix(tf)
#     Terms
# Docs hello super world
#    1     1     1     1
#    2     1     0     2

as.matrix(tfidf)
#     Terms
# Docs hello     super world
#    1     0 0.3333333     0
#    2     0 0.0000000     0
```